# How do i share connection port between containers? Docker

Tags: docker, redis, laravel-echo

I'm trying to install `laravel-echo-server` & `redis` into 2 containers. Since `laravel-echo-server` depends on `redis`, I made my configuration on `docker-compose.yml` like below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - laravel_echo_server_network

  laravel_echo_server:
    image: laravel_echo_server:latest
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - laravel_echo_server_network

networks:
  laravel_echo_server_network:
```

But it seems won't reach my laravel-echo-server containers. How do I connect them?

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.3

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
```

Dockerfile

```
# Install Node
FROM node:18

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . /var/www

# Install
RUN npm install -g laravel-echo-server

# npm run start
CMD ["laravel-echo-server", "start"]
```